# Animating angular d3 donut on load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, d3.js

I have created a simple Angular/D3 donut chart.

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/NyH1udkjBj3zymhGaThZ?p=preview

However i want the chart to have an animation on page load. In that, i mean, i would like the filled (blue area) to transition in.

Somethign similar to: http://codepen.io/tpalmer/pen/jqlFG/

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <d3-donut radius="radius" percent="percent" text="text"></d3-donut>
div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.directive('d3Donut', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      radius: '=',
      percent: '=',
      text: '=',
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

      var radius = scope.radius;
      var percent = scope.percent;
      var text = scope.text;

      var svg = d3.select(element[0])
        .append('svg')
        .style('width', radius / 2 + 'px')
        .style('height', radius / 2 + 'px');

      var donutScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 100]).range([0, 2 * Math.PI]);
      var color = "#5599aa";
      var data = [
        [0, 100, "#e2e2e2"],
        [0, percent, color]
      ];

      var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(radius / 6)
        .outerRadius(radius / 4)
        .startAngle(function(d) {
          return donutScale(d[0]);
        })
        .endAngle(function(d) {
          return donutScale(d[1]);
        });

      svg.selectAll("path")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", arc)
        .style("fill", function(d) {
          return d[2];
        })
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + radius / 4 + "," + radius / 4 + ")");

      svg.append("text")
        .attr("x", radius / 4)
        .attr("y", radius / 4)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("font-size", "12px")
        .style("fill", "#333")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(text);
    }
  };
});

function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.radius = 200;
  $scope.percent = 50;
  $scope.text = "40%";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have combined your code with the one you cited as an example. Here is a working [PLUNK](http://plnkr.co/edit/SjwdqEojaIhSzFHEc8U4?p=preview).

Two things are worth noting - 
1. using `attrTween`:

```
.attrTween("d", function (a) {
    var i  = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
    var i2 = d3.interpolate(progress, percent)
    this._current = i(0);
    console.log(this._current);
    return function(t) {
        text.text( format(i2(t) / 100) );
        return arc(i(t));
    };
});
```

2. updating the data:

```
data = [
    [0,100,"#e2e2e2"],
    [0,percent,color]
];
```

I did some other less important changes like a more idiomatic use of the controller snippet, etc., but the above is what matters.

Answer (score -1):

Would the Angular 'run' command help here?

```
angular.module('app', []).run(myfunction($rootScope))
```

See 'run' on this page https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module
'run()' will give you one-time only execution of so-and-so a function once AngularJs has bootstrapped.